# If my base controller has override void Dispose() that disposes dbcontext, do I need to dispose it in child controller?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

In my BaseController

```
public class BaseController : Controller
    {
        protected ApplicationDbContext context;

        public BaseController()
        {
           context = new ApplicationDbContext();
        }

        protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
        {
            context.Dispose();
            base.Dispose(disposing);
        }

    }
```

And in my HomeController

```
    public class HomeController : BaseController
        {
            public HomeController ()
            {
            }

//is this method still necessary?
            protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
            {
                context.Dispose();
                base.Dispose(disposing);
            }
    }
```

If my BaseController already has `override void Dispose(bool disposing)` that disposes dbcontext, does it mean that the controller that extends it no longer needs to have `override void Dispose(bool disposing)` that disposes dbcontext?

Answer (score 2):

When you inherit from a class that implements `IDisposable`, you should only override the `Dispose(bool)` method if you have some cleanup of your *own* to do.

You should always assume that the base class(es) are cleaning up *their messes* and just take care of new mess that you've created (if you need to), and let them do it by calling `base.Dispose` *if* you've overriding `Dispose`.

(Similarly, if you're authoring a base class yourself with disposable resources, you should make sure you clean up your own mess in your own `Dispose`).

Comment: thank you, so in my HomeController to dispose context it's enough to call `base.Dispose(disposing);` ?

Comment: @HeeroYuy - yes, but only do that if you've got a reason to override `Dispose(bool)` at all, which it doesn't look like you do here so, basically, don't write *any* dispose code in `HomeController` (unless/until it gains some disposable resources of its own)